# Reading Nested NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Evening all!

I'm trying to use data from a 'nested' (I think that's the correct terminology) NSMutableDictionary. Please see below:

(I get "Property 'product_01' not found on object of type 'NSMutableDictionary *')

Please help? Cheers!

```
    NSMutableDictionary *appVariables = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{
                                                                                     @"product_01" : @{

                                                                                             @"name" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Door"],
                                                                                             @"description" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Description of door."],
                                                                                             @"size" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:5],
                                                                                             },

                                                                                     @"product_02" : @{

                                                                                             @"name" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Window"],
                                                                                             @"description" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Description of window."],
                                                                                             @"size" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:5],
                                                                                             }
                                                                                     }];

NSLog(@"Name: %@", appVariables.product_01[@"name"]);
NSLog(@"Description: %@", appVariables.product_01[@"description"]);
NSLog(@"Size: %@", appVariables.product_01[@"size"]);

NSLog(@"Name: %@", appVariables.product_02[@"name"]);
NSLog(@"Description: %@", appVariables.product_02[@"description"]);
NSLog(@"Size: %@", appVariables.product_02[@"size"]);
```

Comment: There are plenty of existing topics covering this question, including some under the Related section of your question. You will save yourself time by doing a little searching first.

Comment: There absolutely is but sometimes it's easier for a beginner by getting help in the same context. Thankfully there were helpful people that answered. Sorry for wasting your screen space with my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a more reasonable version of the dictionary:

```
NSMutableDictionary *appVariables = [@{
   @"product_01" : @{
           @"name"        : @"Door",
           @"description" : @"Description of door.",
           @"size"        : @5
           },

   @"product_02" : @{
           @"name"        : @"Window",
           @"description" : @"Description of window.",
           @"size"        : @5
           }
   } mutableCopy];
```

Answer:

```
NSString *item = appVariables[@"product_01"][@"id"];
```

Note:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Description of door."];
```

is unnecessary, just use:

```
@"Description of door."
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use bracket notation whenever you look up into a dictionary, even if it's nested:

```
NSLog(@"Name: %@", appVariables[@"product_01"][@"id"]);
```